# How to get PHP variable from another PHP file?

Tags: php

I have **functions.php**

```
    while ($row_posts = mysqli_fetch_array($run_news)) {

    $news_id = $row_posts['news_id'];
    $user_id = $row_posts['user_id'];
    $topic_id = $row_posts['topic_id'];
    $news_title = $row_posts['news_title'];
    $news_date = $row_posts['news_date'];

    // getting the user who has posted the thread

    $user = "select * from users where user_id ='$user_id' AND posts = 'yes'";

    $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $user);
    $row_user = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user);
    $user_name = $row_user['user_name'];
    $user_image = $row_user['user_image'];
```

And another file **showmap.php** where I want $string to be dynamically come from user

```
$string = 'Massive fire underneath Metro-North tracks in MODEL TOWN disrupts train service.';
$lower_string= strtolower($string);
```

Comment: `include()` the file? Not really sure what you're after...

Comment: classic case of variable scoping

Comment: Well I have included it, but I am getting $news_title  within a while(in function.php) and later on in (showmap.php) I want that title to be as $string

Comment: you need to update your question as to how exactly you're using that. The ***less*** the good people know, the ***more time*** it takes to provide you with a solution. Which in turn, you're asking us to take a blind shot at an invisible target.

Comment: and I for one have waited long enough. wait for a magic answer and good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to have the variable transfer in the same request you must use something like include() or require().

However if the file is redirecting to another php file and you still want the variable to be available you can save it in a SESSION or COOKIE.

Whatever is written inside a session will be available accross multiple php pages.

Here is more about using sessions: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp